# Altium: PCB rule check violation errors

Tags: altium, error

I'm not sure how to change the rules to satisfy the component constraints

[image]

Comment: I suggest you find you an Altium course to take. There is alot of stuff within the software. If this is your job, or you feel that Altium will be used throughout your career, consider http://www.fedevel.com/academy/pricing/ I took one of their courses early on and it improved how I used Altium greatly. And it's MUCH cheaper than any of the official Altium course.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I was meaning to take the advanced course because it covers more topics. Which course have you taken?

Comment: From that link, I took "Learn Altium Essentials" and "Advanced Hardware Design". The Advanced one was the most beneficial, and its cheap. Both courses for $150. Altium charges like $2000 for their basic course, which yes but I didn't learn much from the Altium course that I didn't learn from the Fedeval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up your PCB and Violations panel, you can see all your errors. Double click on one of the errors, and a pop up will appear. Jump to the error, so it fills the screen, and the highlight it, so you know exactly where it is.

You can find all the rules within the Design->Rules
Go through the list, and you can find all the rules including the ones in your Message panel.